# How to check if the location service is "on" in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, service, location

My app works with location. So I it is required to be location service on. I have seen questions about checking location service's status on the [iOS platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914350/how-to-check-if-location-services-is-on-or-not), but is there a way to check this in the shared project?

I'm looking for an event type solution where if the user turns off the location service, the app will stop what it was doing and ask the user to turn on the location again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **DependencyService** to see if the location is turned on.

Here is my cs code:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var check = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceOrientationService>().IsLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (check)
    {
        res.Text = "It is on";
    }
    else
    {
        res.Text = "It is off";
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the implementation of my method (in App.Android):

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceOrientationService))]
namespace App13.Droid
{
    class DeviceOrientationService : IDeviceOrientationService
    {
        public bool IsLocationServiceEnabled()
        {
           LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
           return locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: All the people are giving down votes to demotivate me where you gave me a hope.

Comment: Wish you success

Comment: I was facing the same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DependancyService to see if the location is turned on. Some people reading this issue might wonder how to do it on iOS too, so I'll walk you through it.

First, shall we create an interface in the Service folder of our shared code containing:

```
public interface IGpsDependencyService
{ 
        bool IsGpsTurnedOn();
        void OpenSettings();
}
```

There are two functions here:

- **IsGpsTurnedOn():** to check if the GPS is on
- **OpenSettings():** to open the location setting page for the user to turn the GPS feature on.

##### Now we need to craft the native code behind these two functions:

Create GpsDependancyService.cs in a Service folder for both our iOS and Android projects

In the iOS, let's write:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GpsDependencyService))]

namespace YourApp.iOS.Services
{
    public class GpsDependencyService : IGpsDependencyService
    {

        public bool IsGpsTurnedOn()
        {
            if (CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            var WiFiURL = new NSUrl("prefs:root=WIFI");

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(WiFiURL))
            {   //> Pre iOS 10
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(WiFiURL);
            }
            else
            {   //> iOS 10
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("App-Prefs:root=WIFI"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for Android, we can write:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GpsDependencyService))]
namespace YourApp.Droid.Services
{

    public class GpsDependencyService : IGpsDependencyService
    {
        public bool IsGpsTurnedOn()
        {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            return locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
        }

        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocat‌​ionSourceSettings);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            try
            {
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(activityNotFoundException.Message);
                Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Error: Gps Activity", Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Now, all we have to do is to call these two functions in our lovely beloved code!

- to use **IsGpsTurnedOn():** DependencyService.Get().IsGpsTurnedOn();
- to use **OpenSettings():** DependencyService.Get().OpenSettings();

I hope it helps, don't hesitate to ask me questions in the comment

---

**Source:** https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1257#issuecomment-623029612

Comment: Why does this have to be complicated?
Why not use the built in abstracted non platform specific Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions class.
Well, thats what i do, what am I missing here?

Comment: @axa Why not create your own answer if you have a better solution? 

Comment: Well, as suggested by the 2 question marks used in the comment, it was more of a question than an answer.